# Issue in setting global array value with onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to set globally defined `String[] placesSuggestion;` using `onPostExecute` of the `AsyncTask<String, String, String[]>`

The `onPostExecute` method looks like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] suggestionArray){
        //Log.d("suggestionArray", Arrays.toString(suggestionArray));
        super.onPostExecute(suggestionArray);
        fillPlacesSuggestion(suggestionArray);
        Log.d("suggestionArray", Arrays.toString(suggestionArray));
    }
```

`fillPlacesSuggestion` function looks like this :

```
public void fillPlacesSuggestion(String[] suggestionArray){
    placesSuggestion = suggestionArray;
}
```

`onCreate` method looks like this :

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sourceET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sourceEditText);
    destinationET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.destinationEditText);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    Log.d("placesSuggestion", Arrays.toString(placesSuggestion));
```

The `suggestionArray` log is giving out the expected value but `placeSuggestion` log is not.

Can anyone help me out in resolving the issue as I am very new to Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to log this :

```
Log.d("placesSuggestion", Arrays.toString(placesSuggestion));
```

the task is not yet finished. Wait for it if you want to get right value for placesSuggestion

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute();
if (task.get() != null) // waiting for it
{
    Log.d("placesSuggestion", Arrays.toString(placesSuggestion));
}
```

Comment: This would likely cause a crash (since it would cause the task to execute the background task on the main thread).

Comment: Not exactly according to the doc "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result." But i agree that's not the best idea, it was just for the sake of the asked issue.

Comment: Right, it wouldn't necessarily cause a crash, but it would cause the task to execute in the UI thread. If that task accessed the network, then you would crash with a NetworkOnMainThreadException.